# Text Encoding for Kindle with Python

Tags: python, encoding, kindle, latin1

Basicly, I'm crawling text from a webpage with python using Beautifulsoup, then save it as an HTML and send it to my Kindle as a mail attachement. The problem is; Kindle supports Latin1(ISO-8859-1) encoding, however the text I'm parsing includes characters that are not a part of Latin1. So when I try to encode text as Latin1 python gives following error because of the illegal characters:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2019'
>   in position 17: ordinal not in range(256)

When I try to encode it as **UTF-8**, this time script runs perfectly but Kindle replaces some incompatible characters with gibberish.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code, if you want us to help you fix it.

Comment: What Kindle version are you using? It seems that Unicode is supported starting from version 3 (see [here](https://www.goodreads.com/author_blog_posts/5809778-kindle-support-for-unicode-pt1-dispelling-a-myth)).

Answer (score 0):

Use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

I previously used `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`, which did not seem to work.